# The active test run was aborted. Reason:

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage

I'm trying to add a .runsettings file in order to exclude the test projects from the code coverage calculations. Everything works fine until I add the DataCollector section, then I get the error message "The active test run was aborted. Reason:" (I really wish they'd give me a reason)

I've stripped my .runsettings file down to the bare minimum, if I remove the  it runs fine but doesn't collect code coverage information, if I include the  it logs that error in the output window and doesn't return code coverage information. If I don't use the .runsettings file it runs without error and returns code coverage information.

I'm using VS 2017 15.8.2 (also tried 15.9.0 Preview 1.0), tests are nUnit.

```
<DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" >
    <Configuration>
      <CodeCoverage>
        <ModulePaths>
          <Include></Include>
          <Exclude></Exclude>
        </ModulePaths>

        <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
        <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
        <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

      </CodeCoverage>
    </Configuration>
  </DataCollector>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using custom settings for code coverage, we recommend that you keep following sections

```
<DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
       <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
           <ModulePaths>
              <Exclude>
                 <ModulePath>.*nunit.*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
           </ModulePaths>
           <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
           <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
           <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
           <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
           <Functions>
              <Exclude>
                 <Function>^std::.*</Function>
                 <Function>^ATL::.*</Function>
                 <Function>.*::__GetTestMethodInfo.*</Function>
                 <Function>.*__CxxPureMSILEntry.*</Function>
                 <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppCodeCoverageFramework::.*</Function>
                 <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::.*</Function>
                 <Function>.*::YOU_CAN_ONLY_DESIGNATE_ONE_.*</Function>
                 <Function>^__.*</Function>
                 <Function>.*::__.*</Function>
              </Exclude>
           </Functions>
           <Attributes>
              <Exclude>
                 <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
                 <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                 <Attribute>^System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
                 <Attribute>^System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                 <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
                 <Attribute>^Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode.*</Attribute>
              </Exclude>
           </Attributes>
           <PublicKeyTokens>
              <Exclude>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^B77A5C561934E089$</PublicKeyToken>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^B03F5F7F11D50A3A$</PublicKeyToken>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^31BF3856AD364E35$</PublicKeyToken>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^89845DCD8080CC91$</PublicKeyToken>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^71E9BCE111E9429C$</PublicKeyToken>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^8F50407C4E9E73B6$</PublicKeyToken>
                 <PublicKeyToken>^E361AF139669C375$</PublicKeyToken>
              </Exclude>
           </PublicKeyTokens>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
```

Since you are running nUnit based test, I've added section to exclude nUnit dlls from coverage.

Other sections that I've added are:

- Certain Attributes we exclude, e.g. DebuggerHiddenAttribute, CompilerGeneratedAttribute etc
- Assemblies signed with certain public key tokens, generally used by Microsoft
- Some default C++ functions(library), e.g std, ATL, etc.

Since we do runtime profiling, these tend to cause errors, leading into crashes at times.

For more details on how to configure your coverage runsettings, please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2017